# How to manually define trusted paths for directory local variables '.dir-locals.el'?

Tags: directory-local-variables

I would like to define a list of trusted paths.

- Where `dir-locals.el` can be loaded without asking me.
- Without having to be concerned with `safe-local-variable-values`
  *Which isn't very practical if the value contains code which might be edited/modified.*

Instead, I would like to have a list of paths, similar to `.gitignore`, which are "trusted" and won't prompt me to trust expressions.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by advising `hack-local-variables-filter`.

```elisp
(defvar my-trusted-paths
  (list
    "/some/path/"
    "/another/path/"))
(defvar my-trusted-paths-prefix
  (list
    "/another/prefix/"
    "/some/prefix/"))

(defun my-trusted-paths-filter (dir-name)
  (catch 'result
    (dolist (p my-trusted-paths)
      (when (string-equal p dir-name)
        (throw 'result t)))
    (dolist (p my-trusted-paths-prefix)
      (when (string-prefix-p p dir-name)
        (throw 'result t)))))

(advice-add 'hack-local-variables-filter
  :around
  #'
  (lambda (old-fn &rest args)
    (pcase-let ((`(,_variables ,dir-name) args))
      (if (my-trusted-paths-filter dir-name)
        (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'safe-local-variable-p) (lambda (&rest _) t)))
          (apply old-fn args)
          ;; Always accept paths matching.
          t)
        (apply old-fn args)))))
```

---

NOTE: I've since moved to a package that is an alternative to `dir-locals` that allows out-of-source locals called [sidecar-locals](https://gitlab.com/ideasman42/emacs-sidecar-locals).